# Can astronauts hear sounds during space walks for repairs?

Tags: iss, sound

We know there is no sound in space in a vacuum, but when an astronaut is outside on a spacewalk doing repairs, can they hear the tapping when they use a hammer or the sound of a power screwdriver etc.?

Comment: I would strongly assume they can't, that's the point about space not propagating sounds. Is there any specific reason why you think they could?

Comment: Related question with examples of sounds that can be heard: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/23851/where-does-the-noise-on-spacewalks-come-from

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can astronauts inside ISS hear their crewmates doing EVAs?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/20886/can-astronauts-inside-iss-hear-their-crewmates-doing-evas)

Comment: If the suit or the body of the astronaut conduct the noise of the tools to the head with the ears, the astronaut will hear it. Sound is conducted not only by an atmosphere, but also by solids. But a high attenuation of the noise will make the sound unhearable.

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape consider bone conduction for example. There is a mechanical path to consider, either through hands or feet. You've misrepresented the question by suggesting space is the only path. I think it's a good question and deserves an authoritative answer.

Comment: @DarkDust or other close-voters; could someone explain how a question about "an astronaut... outside on a spacewalk" could be a duplicate of a question about "astronauts inside ISS"? Is this really a valid close reason?

Comment: @uhoh: Well, the questions have a basic similarity: they're both about sound from spacewalk operations conducting through solid objects to an atmosphere for an astronaut to hear. Given that, I'm not convinced the distinction between large atmosphere inside and small atmosphere in suit outside is significant.

Comment: @NathanTuggy the question is about what an astronaut experiences while **inside of a spacesuit** on a spacewalk **outside of the ISS**. There's no way an answer about what an **unsuited** astronaut hears inside the ISS day-to-day is going to address what the spacewalk experience is actually like. You are presupposing the answer, and closing denies you, me, and everyone else the opportunity to find out otherwise. Why not wait to see what the answer actually is! On the other hand, if you have *first-hand experience* on a spacewalk yourself, you could consider posting an answer.

Comment: @uhoh: But the answer *does* address it. Can you be clearer about what you think makes such an enormous difference? Is it that the ISS might somehow amplify sounds, or that the spacesuit might somehow muffle them, or might just not conduct them at all? (Spoiler: I'm reasonably convinced none of those is the case.) Or are you just committed to ignoring actual answers out of principle in order to ensure only topic-agnostic question-to-question matching occurs? I don't think that's the best (much less the only) principle to use, but I can respect that anyway.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I've tried to be more clear about it in [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/24204/12102). I'm not an expert nor an anstronaut, but I've posted this in order to provide readers with some science before the *insta-close* happens.

Comment: @uhoh: You're right, I misread the question, my bad. This question is actually the "other side" of my question. Have retracted my close vote.

Comment: @uhoh You misread? This only goes to show äutorithies can do things by halve!

Answer (score 14):

According to WIRED Magazine's article and video [Watch Astronauts Answer Your Burning Questions about Space](https://www.wired.com/story/watch-astronauts-answer-your-burning-questions-about-space/) (also viewable on [YouTube](https://youtu.be/dikG4vMJG1s)):

> Sounds exist in space, but humans can not hear them.

[image: Watch Astronauts Answer Your Burning Questions about Space]

[image: Watch Astronauts Answer Your Burning Questions about Space]

As pointed out in the question, there is not going to be any significant, perceptible sound transmitted through space at the altitude of the ISS (now roughly 400 km). The density is so low and the mean free path so long that any tiny, residual amounts of sound that could potentially be transmitted (by an anomalously high local pressure (see below, [or **especially here**](https://youtu.be/gpwvJzcfL1w?t=63) but lower your volume a bit first)) would be lost at the first interface between the extremely small atmosphere and the solid materials of the astronaut's helmet due to [acoustic impedance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acoustic_impedance) mismatch.

In the [video](https://youtu.be/9yRWhu0UGYw?t=25) referenced by [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/19436/12102) you can hear both acoustic sound transmitted through the low pressure atmosphere recorded by the camera's microphone at the lower altitudes, as well as some mechanical or "[microphonics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microphonics)" as discussed in the [excellent answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/19440/12102). Microphonics can also be heard in [the video](https://youtu.be/26QWMMT1c8Y) discussed in the question [What are the sounds in this GoPro-in-orbit ISS video?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/20786/12102).

If the astronaut were working in the vicinity of a serious, large gas leak, or in any other highly unusual situation where there was a much larger atmosphere, one should not be absolutely certain no sound perception could be possible. It should not be explicitly ruled out, though very unlikely.

However, for *hand tools* held by an astronaut, there is a possibility of microphonics via [bone conduction](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/12/08/science/why-we-hear-some-silent-gifs.html), though this would require conduction through the suit's gloves, so the chances are very low.

Finally, as an aside, there is always a possibility of perceived, or mis-assigned sound cues. See for example the New York Times article [Why We ‘Hear’ Some Silent GIFs](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/12/08/science/why-we-hear-some-silent-gifs.html) and the scientific references within, as well as [this tweet](https://twitter.com/lisadebruine/status/937302328184594432) by Lisa Debruine, a researcher at the Institute of Neuroscience and Psychology at the University of Glasgow.

[image: GIF from https://twitter.com/lisadebruine/status/937302328184594432]

Comment: That GIF not only produces phantom "sound", but also phantom sensations of vibration.

Comment: Fantastic answer! And that GIF not only makes me feel, hear or experience phantom sensations, it also makes me laugh! +1

Answer (score 13):

Many years ago, as a young engineer, I worked for Hamilton Standard who developed the Space Suit, and which had the remit to develop a Power Tool for Astronauts for the purposes of repairing the Space Telescope while in orbit.  We interviewed astronauts regarding their experiences working 'extravehicular' ...meaning in space, mainly at that point, in the payload bay of the space shuttle. It became apparent due to 1) the vacuum of space and 2) due to the multiple layers of the glove [2 at the time], they could not hear what they were working on.  i.e. the click of a quick disconnect, or when approaching a pump coolant system that was working in space, no ability to hear which of the 2 pumps was 'stopped' vs 'working'.  Working with United Technologies Research Center, to solve this problem, we found a piezoelectic polymer film which could be inserted into the glove, and act as a contact microphone. This film, was then connected to a mini amplifier and speakers, which meant that the astronaut could 'hear' through their hands [gloves]....whatever they were touching, they could hear.  As a young engineer I was given an honorary NASA distinction for this, but I left the company soon after and never would know whether they fully qualified or implemented this solution.  Would love to know.

Comment: This is a great answer! I see that you are an unregistered user, but hopefully some day you will return to see that I've just asked [Can space suit gloves hear, feel, or otherwise sense information through augmentation? Will they?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/46428/12102)