# Did the Apollo astronauts hear any external sounds during a lunar EVA?

Tags: eva, sound, apollo-program

Did any sounds resonate through their boots or any part of their environmental suit?  Could they hear the folding or rubbing of the material of their suits?  Did anything impact their boots that might have cause a vibration to travel to their ear drum/ear canal?

Comment: The path for sound from the boots to the ears of the astronaut within the atmosphere inside the EVA suit was restricted by the underwear and the liquid cooling garment. Thus the sound from the boots would be absorbed.

Comment: different but related: [Can astronauts hear sounds during space walks for repairs?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/24201/12102)